# How to set target machine in a Visual Studio C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, properties, configuration

I am developping a C# project on Visual Studio 2012.
I need to integrate an ActiveX dll 32 bit to my project.

On Properties I set:

Configuration: Active(Release) - Platform Active(x86)

If I try to run my project on another machine (64x) this error occurs:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

 Exception Text 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4834FB7D-E55B-4508-94E8-75A162D25A18} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at ED_Model_Loader.Form1.btnED_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Fabio\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ED Model Loader\ED Model Loader\Form1.cs:line 31
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


 Loaded Assemblies 
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
ED Model Loader
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/amore.c/Desktop/ED%20Model%20Loader/ED%20Model%20Loader/ED%20Model%20Loader/bin/Release/ED%20Model%20Loader.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34250 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

Have you some idea how to solve this issue?

EDIT:
I solved this issue running the third part software with administrator rights on the target machines. The user of the target machine installed the third part software without administrator right and probably on its machine there weren't the runtime dlls needed.

Thanks
Fabio

Comment: Have you registered the DLL on both machines?

Comment: Did you set the platform target?

Comment: The class is not registered on the target machine. Use regsvr32 to register it.

Comment: @OguzOzgul Probably I haven't registered the ActiveX dll on the target machine. How can I do that? using the comnad regsvr32 on ActiveX.exe it doesn't run well.

Comment: What does it report when you run regsvr32? It probably has some dependencies which you should also copy to the target server. Is it ActiveX.exe or ActiveX.dll?

Comment: @OguzOzgul The module "ActiveX.exe" waas loaded but entry-point DllRefisterServer was not found. Make sure that "ActiveX.exe" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again

Comment: Can you search the local registry (regedit then CTRL + F) the GUID 4834FB7D-E55B-4508-94E8-75A162D25A18 ? If we can see what class it is, we can register that class on the target server

Comment: @OguzOzgul I found it. It is the Clsid of my ActiveX object. How can I register it on the target machine?

Comment: You should have an OCX file right? Use regsvr32 with that

Comment: @OguzOzgul the problem was that the user of the target machine installed the third part software without administrator rights. Running the third part software with administrator rights my project works well. Thanks for your support!